BigQuery: Concatenate a repeated field with a no repeated field
Given the BigQuery table:
| id | extra_field | field1 | field2 |
| -- | ----------- | ------ | ------ |
| 1  | row1        | a      | [b,c]  |
| 2  | row2        | x      | [y,z]  |
| 2  | row3        | t      | []     |

I want to combine the field1 and field2 for each row in order to generate a new field3 that contains an array with the combination as follows:
| id | extra_field | field3  |
| -- | ----------- | ------- | 
| 1  | row1        | [a,b,c] |
| 2  | row2        | [x,y,z] |
| 3  | row3        | [t]     |


use below approach (assuming: field1 is string and field2 is array)
select id, extra_field, [field1] || field2 as field3
from your_table

